# How to randomly change boolean value in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to randomly assign a 'True' value to a list of booleans. When I run the code, I keep getting an error. Here's the code:

```
    for x in population:
        if x:
            r = random.randint(0, len(population))
            population[r] = True
```

Which keeps throwing the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
     population[r] = True
 IndexError: list assignment index out of range"
```

I'm sure it's something trivial, but I can't figure it out. How is the index assignment out of range when I constrain it to within the length of the list?

Comment: Are you sure this logic makes sense for what you're doing? Consider for example the case where the first element is true, so another element will be set to true that may have been false before... then that element will trigger another setting operation, *in the same pass over the population*. Is that what you want? It would help to explain what you're trying to model. I suspect an XY problem here.

Comment: I didn't see that before. You're right though.... if an element is made True, then another element (possibly down the line) is made true as well. Then once the for loop reaches that changed element, it would trigger yet another random assignment. The answer is no, that's not what I wanted to do. I want a single random assignment every time the for loop runs. If it helps, I'm writing a simple program that estimates the time until an entire population is infected by a virus (modeled like a game of tag). One person is it, they infect a random everyday, and those infected continue the cycle.

Comment: What you might want to do is compute how many elements to update, and then randomly choose that many of them to update. For example, you could use `random.sample` on a `range` to get the indices to set, and set them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) returns a number between a and b **inclusive**. If the result of the function call equals `len(population)`, then you're trying to do `population[len(population)]`, which will raise an IndexError because indexing starts at 0.

Simple change: Just minus 1 from `len(population)`:

```
r = random.randint(0, len(population)-1)
```

Or use [`randrange(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange), which is not inclusive:

```
r = random.randrange(len(population))
```

Note that if the first argument is 0 we don't need it since it will assume the start is 0.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), `random.randint(a, b)`

> Return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`.

Since arrays are indexed starting at 0 in Python, `len(population)` is outside the range of the array (hence your error). As @TerryA indicated, you actually want the range to be from `0` to `len(population) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
for x in population:
        if x:
            r = random.randint(0, len(population)-1)
            population[r] = True
```

Comment: You have a typo. `=` should be `-`